# Filtering data from Struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

```
S.o     = [{'A'} ,{'B'}, {'C'}];
S.p.q   = [{'q1'}, {'q2'}, {'q3'}];
S.p.q.a = [-1,-2,-3];
S.p.q.b = [10,20,30];
```

How do i create another struct (S_filter) in Matlab for S.o = 'A' or 'C' only:

```
    S_filter.o     = [{'A'} ,{'C'}];
    S_filter.p.q   = [{'q1'}, {'q3'}];
    S_filter.p.q.a = [-1,-3];
    S_filter.p.q.b = [10,30];

Thanks
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don’t post amendments as comments as they can be deleted easily.

Comment: Considering the structure of your data, the easiest way to do what you want is to index in each struct field separately. If you can reorganize your struct, you can make indexing easier: `S(2).o='B'; S(3).p.a=1;`, etc.